# Upgrade from 5.0.4 to 5.1.1 causes $theme to be null

Tags: theme-development, upgrade

When we upgrade from 5.0.4 to 5.1.1 the site stops loading.

The error message is

```
Fatal error:  Uncaught Error: Call to a member function images_path() on null 
/wp-content/themes/mytheme/header.php on line 49
```

Line 49 is 
`<?php $theme->images_path(); ?>`

above it in the same file is
`global $theme;`

$theme is created in functions.php as the instance of our custom theme.

```
class MyTheme {
  private $theme_name = "MyTheme";
  private $scripts_version = '0.90';

  function __construct() {
    add_action('init', array($this, 'init_assets'));
    ...several of these
  ...more methods
  }
}
...other stuff
$theme = new MyTheme();
```

I don't know how to troubleshoot this issue. Everything worked great prior to the upgrade and no other changes were made to the site.

Any help appreciated.

Comment: What related code exists before line 49? Variables defined in functions.php are not automatically available in template files. Assuming you renamed $theme to $lp_theme, you should probably be doing a `global $lp_theme;` before trying to use it.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Since [Changeset 44524](https://core.trac.wordpress.org/changeset/44524), which has landed in WordPress 5.1, the variable `$theme` is now a global variable set by WordPress which also gets unset [after the themes have been bootstrapped](https://core.trac.wordpress.org/browser/tags/5.1.1/src/wp-settings.php?marks=476-482#L476):

```
// Load the functions for the active theme, for both parent and child theme if applicable.
foreach ( wp_get_active_and_valid_themes() as $theme ) {
    if ( file_exists( $theme . '/functions.php' ) ) {
        include $theme . '/functions.php';
    }
}
unset( $theme );
```

This means that any value set by your theme gets also unset.

To fix the fatal error you now have to replace all variables named `$theme` with a prefixed version, for example `$my_theme`. Prefixing variables and functions in global scope is considered best practice to avoid such issues.

Comment: I still haven't gotten the fix to resolve in my instance, but we ran some isolated tests of the issue and you are spot on about the cause and resolution. Bravo

Answer (score 1):

Always check for reserved terms and global variables to avoid possible conflicts.

An overview can be found at the WordPress Codex:

- [Reserved Terms](https://codex.wordpress.org/Reserved_Terms)
- [Global Variables](https://codex.wordpress.org/Global_Variables)

Note: Those lists might not be always be 100% up-to-date, so inspecting the version of the source code you're using is the only possibility to be 100% sure.